# Stop it from uploading .sass files?

Tags: aptana

Is there a way to get Aptana Studio 3 to not upload specific file extensions, such as .sass for example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have the project set up with a remote server, you could right-click on a .sass file in the project and select **Deploy** > **Cloak this file type**.

You could also go to **Preferences** > **Aptana Studio** > **Remote** and add .sass to the list of file extensions to be ignored.